# How to query all geoqueries in a set radius with geofirestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints, geofirestore

I am trying to make a query to a cloud-firestore which should return all geopoints within a radius of, say, 10.5 km of a given geopoint. I am trying to use geofirestore to achieve this. I have tried using geoqueries, but i can't find a method or property which returns this. My question seems as if it has a fairly simple answer, but I am new to both firebase and geofirestore. Thank you.

My code so far:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const app = firebase.app();
});

var db = firebase.firestore();

db.settings({
    timestampsInSnapshots: true
});

const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('geofirestore');

// Create a GeoFirestore index
const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef);

const post1 =  db.collection('posts').doc('firstpost');

const test = {lat: 39.369048, long: -76.68229}

const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
    center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(10.38, 2.41),
    radius: 10.5,
    query: (ref) => ref.where('d.count', '==', '1')
});

console.log(geoQuery.query());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the documentation may not be clear, but here's what is going on.

The below code creates a [GeoFirestoreQuery](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore/tree/v2.2.2#geofirestorequery):

```
const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
    center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(10.38, 2.41),
    radius: 10.5,
    query: (ref) => ref.where('d.count', '==', '1')
});
```

If you wanted to make a geoquery you'd use the `on` listener for the `key_entered` event which will return documents in your query, [see here](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore/tree/v2.2.2#geofirestorequeryoneventtype-callback).

However you're calling the `query` function, which returns a Firestore Query, or CollectionReference (depending on if you passed in a query function when you created or updated the query criteria).

Calling `get` on this `query` BYPASSES all of the GeoFirestore magic goodness, and would not provide you with what you want or expect... Instead you'd want to do something like this.

```
// Store all results from geoqueries here
let results = [];

// Create geoquery
const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
    center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(10.38, 2.41),
    radius: 10.5,
    query: (ref) => ref.where('d.count', '==', '1')
});

// Remove documents when they fall out of the query
geoQuery.on('key_exited', ($key) => {
  const index = results.findIndex((place) => place.$key === $key);
  if (index >= 0) results.splice(index, 1);
});

// As documents come in, add the $key/id to them and push them into our results
geoQuery.on('key_entered', ($key, result) => {
  result.$key = $key;
  results.push(result);
});
```

Comment: So 'key_exited' is not an event listener? thank you.

Comment: `key_exited` is an event listener, and you should be able to find it in the example, it's hella useful! =D

Comment: I have this same code and sometimes it works and sometimes it fails with: Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted. Shouldn't there be an await somewhere?

Comment: No await is needed, if you show some code or maybe share a gist I can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

use .near
see geofirestore.com for more

```
const query = geocollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(40.7589, -73.9851), radius: 1000 });

// Get query (as Promise)
query.get().then((value) => {
  console.log(value.docs);
});
```